# Drawing a circle in a matrix in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am following the book learning opencv

([https://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/0596516134](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) and then link to book https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9a67/4d82cd4f47477e3f1aa7b89a3d9f6e3894b8.pdf?_ga=2.62513452.1463426740.1585949302-836919348.1585949302)

I am working through an exercise;

"The is exercise will accustom you to the idea of many functions taking matrix types.
Create a two-dimensional matrix with three channels of type byte with data size
100-by-100. Set all the values to 0.

a. Draw a circle in the matrix using `void cvCircle( CvArr* img, CvPoint center,
intradius, CvScalar color, int thickness=1, int line_type=8, int shift=0 ).`

b. Display this image using methods described in Chapter 2."

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main () {

  CvPoint Center = cvPoint(50,50);

  CvMat mat = cvMat(
             100,
             100,
             CV_8UC3,             
);
  CvCircle Circle = cvCircle( //I have also tried just "void cvCircle()"
        &mat,  
        Center,
        50
        );
  return 0;
}
```

I dont have a problem with part b of the problem its just mainly part a. Also a a part of my problem could also just be c++ related. In the description of `cvMat` the fourth argument is listed as `void* data = NULL` which I assume means its clearing all the entries in the matrix in order for its values to be set. If this is the case I do not know how to set the values to 0.

Where I declare `Center` I am attempting to set the origin of the circle in the center of the matrix although I am not sure how to tell `cvCircle` how. I wrote 50,50 in hopes that since you initially tell the function its working with `mat` that it will know that is the center of the matrix, but that was a complete shot in the dark.

I do get errors like "CvCircle was not declared in this scope" or "variable or field cvCircle declared void" when using void. This could be pure compiling issues or I am not including the right header files (which I am doubtful of).

Comment: You're attempting to use the OpenCV C API, which has been deprecated since around 2013 and no longer present in OpenCV 4.x. Use the C++ API. | Keep in mind that book was published 12 years ago -- the library has changed a lot over that time. The techniques described there are most likely still useful, but don't expect to be able to just copy the code (not to mention it won't be very useful to learn an obsolete API).

Comment: An argument like "void* data = NULL" means, if you do not specify this argument, it defaults to the NULL pointer. Please start your variables consistently with lowercase letters. So you can better distinguish types and variables and avoid name clashes.

Comment: @DanMašek I currently have OpenCV 2 on ubuntu 19.10. The same book has been published with OpenCV 3. Would I be safe from similar issues using OpenCV 3 instead of 4 (from the looks of it this version of the book does use the C++ API https://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/1491937998)

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea. Keep in mind there are some changes in the API between 3.x and 4.x -- it's a good idea to cross-reference the book with the documentation matching the version of OpenCV you're currently using. (Not to mention it's useful to get familiar with the docs -- they can answer a lot of your questions).

Comment: Ok thank you on that one. I assume the documentation on GitHub coincides with openCV 4

Comment: GIthub has the source code, and you use tags to select whichever release you want. The documentation I had in mind is here: https://docs.opencv.org/